# Android Oreo background location limits

Tags: android, location, android-8.0-oreo

So, in a few words I'm using android.location to get my location and I don't see any difference between when the app is in foreground or background. My first thought was about the fact that Android said to us to use Google Location Services API to get the location. I also tested it with that (Google Location Services API) and it works the same. No difference when getting the location between foregound and background.

My question is this: do you know any reason why it works the same? Knowing that https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html told us that when the app is in background we will get slower callbacks with the location("Apps can receive location updates only a few times each hour").

Thanks!

Comment: Check if your targetSdkVersion is lower than 26

Comment: google didn't say anything about the targetSDKVersion. I don't think it matters what targetSDKVersion it's used.

Comment: @Nikaoto [These limitations apply to all apps used on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, regardless of an app's target SDK version.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)

Answer (score -1):

Bravo Google. So they wants to reduce power consumption by restrictik services/background tasks. All trackers of apps which are trying to work with location will have to be runned in foreground with LCD on. That would probably does not any good to power saving.

They dont have even effort to specifi number of scans per hour.

I they added new permission like, permit background tasks with location without limit, they would to better.

Android 8 will be very successful version. Because target sdk will no make a difference, not like when runtime permission model was added.